# What world is he talking about?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

" This is not easy to figure out", said Grandpa

> " In this world,
>
> **403 = 308 and is same as 83**"
>
> I couldn't figure that one obviously.
>
> " Here is a hint. 5 1 9 2" Grandpa spoke slowly.

What is he counting??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This counting with serious prompting from OP (perhaps Grandpa himself?) involves

> an electronic display 
>  [image]
>  
>  then counting the segments lit-up by the spelled numbers: 
>  403 = FOUR HUNDRED THREE = 4,6,5,6 (21) + 5,5,5,6,6,5,6 (38) + 3,5,6,5,5  (24)  = 83
>  308 = THREE HUNDRED EIGHT is above as EIGHT is 5,2,6,5,3 = 21
>  so 403 = 308 and both use 83 segments.

The Hint: "5 1 9 2" Grandpa spoke slowly.

> FONT (which is 7-seg here) used as clued by the initials "Five One Nine Two"

This method was also seen by [Arnaud](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57057/arnaud-mortier) and OP deemed needed [solving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80440/who-has-more-ireland-or-iceland/80447?noredirect=1#comment234775_80447). (I hadn't got this.)

---

Second try:  In this world, what is he counting? Well, Grandpa knows

> Roman numerals, so he may be counting the number of different letters when written in this form. 
>   403 = 308 and is same as 83
>  403 = CDIII → C,D,I
>  308 = CCCVIII → C,V,I
>  83 = LXXXIII → L,X,I
>  all using 3 different letters.

And "5 1 9 2" Grandpa spoke slowly, as he was counting the

> and also 5 = V uses 1 letter, 9 = IX uses 2 different letters.

---

First non-standard try

> Counting all (not-distinct) letters
>  403 = CCCCIII (usually 400 = CD, but rarely four C's is seen)
>  308 = CCCVIII
>  & 83 = LXXXIII, all having seven letters.

Comment: That is another way of looking at it. Take a look at the hint. Five One Nine Two.

Comment: @DEEM - tried again without using a non-standard form :P

Comment: F      O     N      T       first letters of the hint  Dig it?

Comment: Added the clue (surprisingly seen before try but didn't make a connection) and not 100% certain this ans is it!

Comment: OK. I am going to post a puzzle tomorrow which will be a direct clue to this one.