# Who has more? Ireland or Iceland?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

> China has three more than Chile
>
> Algeria has two more than Nigeria
>
> Ireland has _____  more than Iceland. Or other way around?

How many and why?

This is also a clue to the previous puzzle

**" [What world is he talking about?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80393/what-world-is-he-talking-about)"**

HINT

> It is the way you write it

Comment: Just had a lot of fun [reading this](https://www.boredpanda.com/beautiful-handwriting-lettering-calligraphy) (especially #4), yet still no clue about this puzzle.

Comment: Why only focus on handwriting? There are other ways.......

Comment: Sure, but I'd ruled them out first. Wrongly, obviously.

Comment: I thought this might be something to do with Serif fonts but can't seem to make that work :(

Comment: FONT is the right track.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to count these differences is using

> <s>Seven-segment display</s>  the font: 
>
>  [image]

Using this to count the

> Number of lit-up segments:  $N = 5, A = 6, L = 3, E = 5, I = 2, R = 6, C = 4$
>
>  a) China has three more than Chile: $N + A = 11,  L + E = 8$
>  b) Algeria has two more than Nigeria: $A + L = 9, N + I = 7$
>  c) Ireland has **two** more than Iceland: $R = 6, C = 4$

Comment: Seeing your answer, I thought 'why did I not think of that?' and then I figured the answer is that this puzzle is supposed to be a hint to the previous one by DEEM, for which I'd already ruled out this method. But still, good one (+1)!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, we have the same conclusion as to who has more, and I think they are not unrelated. I still don't know what Grandpa is counting in the previous one.

Comment: This is what I meant with FONT. Now if you spell out the numbers in the previous puzzle in this font FOUR HUNDRED THREE you can count 83 segments

Comment: that's not a seven segment display!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That's not any kind of X-segment display.  It's clearly a font designed to look like one, but no segmented display I've ever seen would have the split top line (as seen in the 'M') and a solid top line for all the other letters, since the segments cannot overlap.  The shortened middle line in the 'G', the diagonals in the 'K' and 'R', and the cross-piece on the 'Q' are also all incorrect for the same reason.

Comment: Thx @JonMarkPerry for pointing this out, and Darrell Hoffman for the top explanation.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman and JonMarkPerry: no it's not just a font, yes that actually is a [16-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteen-segment_display), yes they exist in electronics, as LEDs since at least the 1970s/80s, and in previous forms since 1902. 16-segment displays are like 14-segment displays, with the top and bottom lines split. Obviously all these have been obsoleted by dot-matrix panels with an optional backlight.

Comment: @smci the G, K, Q and R could be 16-segment but the diagonals are in the wrong places and/or bars the wrong length. The M is the only proper 16-segment. The rest are 7-segment (the horizontal bars are not paired).

Answer (score 7):

We have

> $$CHINA=CHILE+3\implies NA=LE+3$$
>  $$ALGERIA=NIGERIA+2\implies AL=NI+2$$

Putting these together gives

> $$A+A=E+I+5$$
>  meaning that $E+I$ is odd. This gives the idea of letting one vertical or horizontal stroke count for $1$, and $2$ for a slanted stroke, then $N=1+2+1$, $I=1$, $A=2+2+1$, and all equations are satisfied.

Now

> ICELAND vs IRELAND means that we need to compare C and R. Now R is basically an inverted C, plus one vertical and one horizontal stroke.

Therefore

> Ireland has three more than Iceland. (Yay! Shamrocks always win!)

Comment: Definitely +1 for th great thought process

Answer (score 1):

Answering the "Or other way round?" part, referring to the [answer from @Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80447)

> **R** is not a seven-segment letter but **r** is, so Ireland is two *less* not two *more* than Iceland.