# Which country has more?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Saw [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80440/who-has-more-ireland-or-iceland?newreg=964c611a341b41da903e49d6a04bd37f) and couldn't help but make it into a different riddle.

> China has three more than Chile
>
> Algeria has one less than Nigeria
>
> Ireland and Iceland...? Are they even different?

HINT

> The numbers are only correct as of this writing, they might change in the future (though unlikely)

Comment: I thought I had a reason but it doesn't work for the second line!

Comment: @Tom, exactly what I thought for the original question, so I made my reason into a question instead.

Comment: That's a nice question with a well chosen hint. Line 2 was correctly clued!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Analyzing this it seems to be counting the number of different

> chemical element symbols consecutively contained in the word.

China has three more than Chile

> We may compare by looking at the last three letters:
>  **ina** has Iodine (I), Indium (In), Nitrogen (N) and Sodium (Na), while **ile** has only Iodine (I).

Algeria has one less than Nigeria

> Then the first three letters:
>  **Alg** has only Aluminium (Al), while **Nig** has Nitrogen (N) and Nickel (Ni) - we don't count Iodine (I) again as Nigeria already has it.

Ireland and Iceland...? Are they even different?

> The first three letters:
>  **Ire** has Iodine (I), Iridium (Ir) and Rhenium (Re), while **Ice** has Iodine (I), Carbon (C) and Cerium (Ce).
>  Hence Ireland = Iceland which is fair and elementary :P

HINT:The numbers are only correct as of this writing, they might change in the future (though unlikely)

> New elements are discovered and named, but it's unlikely they would have symbols contained in the bolded letters.

Comment: We don't count `I` in line 2 because Algeria already has it.